# Create a dual boot with an already existing windows partition

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multi-boot, grub

For the past few months I had an ubuntu with main OS and a windows 11 that I used with kvm/qemu. The whole data is on a distinct partition. Now I want to switch back to a dual boot with windows and ubuntu but I do not want to lose the data I had on my windows. Is there a way to add a windows entrypoint in grub to point to the windows partition ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Use the [Super Grub Disk](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/) and test if it can see the Windows partition as bootable.

Comment: It seems to see the partition as existing but can't boot on it. Also I forgot to mension that I have a img of the partition

Comment: If you can't boot from it then the Super Grub Disk (SGD) can't add it to GRUB, then the Windows installation seems not to be viable without using qemu. You could run Windows Startup Repair on it, but you risk to destroy Grub, although SGD might be able to repair the damage. There are several unknowns here that prevent me from giving a sure answer.

Comment: Ok it seems I'll have to reinstall windows from scratch. Thank you for your help :)